# How to generate a configuration file for SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express, sql-server-2012-express

I want to generate a configuration file for SQL Server 2012 Express, I found Microsoft answer here:

[Install SQL Server 2012 Using a Configuration File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

But there is no Ready to Install page!

[image]

Please help me to accomplish that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution...

To display "Ready to install"  window that allow you to get the path of configuration file follow the steps below:

1- Unpack your SQL setup.exe to C:/

2- Go to that dir via cmd and run: **setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /UIMODE=Normal**

3- Go to the path in the red box and copy the configuration file.

[image]

Hope this help.

Thanks